# Find set with range in python

Tags: python

here is what i have so far, and it works.

```
import itertools
list1=['5','6','7']
list2=['8','9','3']
list3=['10','8','6']
list4=['11','12','9']
list5=['13','5','7']

map(''.join,itertools.chain(itertools.product(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5),itertools.product(list5, list4, list3, list2, list1)))
```

This gives the combination for all numbers. My goal is to get ones that add up 28-30. any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please expand, especially the last section about "all numbers" and "28-30". It feels like I'm missing something.

Comment: You want to find which numbers in that combinations sum is 28-29-30 ?

Comment: so the combanation is gives me is '5,8,10,11,13' which adds up 47. I just want combinations of the numbers that will add up 28,29,30. Is that clear enough. sorry if my previous one was confusing

Comment: @NegouAmanSeid Your method is not correct. Did you check the outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to work with strings and definitely do not join them.
The code below reads self-explanatory almost, one of the key features of a good python code:

```
for combo in itertools.product(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5):
    if 27 < sum(list(map(int,combo))) < 31:
        print(combo)
```

But I'd start by definining your list1 and so on merely as integers, now you have them as lists of strings.

Comment: I think OP's method is wrong because `('6', '3', '6', '9', '5')` is not a combination. It's a permutation. Your output have this one but OP's method is wrong that's because your output is wrong

Comment: Minor: no need for `list`.

Comment: @DSM, correct, that's an artifact from before I noticed OP had strings in his lists. Didn't bother to correct afterwards. @Defalt, I don't understand what you're talking about. If it is about me using the name `combo` for a variable, that's just my way of thinking. Yes, it's a cartesian product.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback I will definitely make the changes to it

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted without giving a reason in the comments, as it is correct. I won't try to understand. Anyway @NegouAmanSeid, welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to consider accepting this answer (or any others if they get posted) if they helped you, as this would signify to the community that you thought it answered your question. At the same time, it will increase your reputation a bit (as well as mine, I won't lie), which is not such a bad thing considering your question was apparently not well-received (but no-one bothered commenting why).

Comment: @oliverw. Hey thank you for your answer. How do I accept the answer? Your answer was really helpful. Thank you again

Comment: Hey @OliverW I have tried the algorithm and I m not sure where I am messing up. Would you able to do a quick example so I could see where I m making my mistake. Thanks